# console_scripts not on path when debianising a python package using dh_virtualenv

Tags: python, linux, debian, deb, debhelper

I have followed the tutorial here https://dh-virtualenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#step-2-setup-the-debian-packaging closely and everything builds and installs fine.

However, my python package usually installs some console scripts, and I would like to be able to install the .deb so that these commands are available globally, i.e. are on the path, rather than only be available when the virtual env in activated.

I could just copy whatever I want from /opt/venvs/my_package/bin/ to /usr/bin/, or some other simple method like that, possibly in the postinst file.

However, what I would like to know is whether there a specific way of doing this that constitutes 'best practice'.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The [dh_virtualenv](https://dh-virtualenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howtos.html#making-executables-available) docs recommend creating symbolink links.

> So use the `debian/«pkgname».links` file to add a symbolic link to those
>   exectuables you want to be visible, typically the one created by your
>   main application package.
>
> `opt/venvs/«venvname»/bin/«cmdname» usr/bin/«cmdname»`

In your console scripts change the shebang `#!` line to use the python executable in `/opt/venvs/my_package/bin` if `dh_virtualenv` hasn't already.